# temporarily retrieve an image using the requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I'm writing a web scraper than needs to scrape only the thumbnail of an image from the url.

This is my function using, the urlib library.

```
def create_thumb(self):
    if self.url and not self.thumbnail:
        image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.url)

        # Create the thumbnail of dimension size
        size = 350, 350
        t_img = Imagelib.open(image[0])
        t_img.thumbnail(size)

        # Get the directory name where the temp image was stored
        # by urlretrieve
        dir_name = os.path.dirname(image[0])

        # Get the image name from the url
        img_name = os.path.basename(self.url)

        # Save the thumbnail in the same temp directory
        # where urlretrieve got the full-sized image,
        # using the same file extention in os.path.basename()
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_name, "thumb" + img_name)
        t_img.save(file_path)

        # Save the thumbnail in the media directory, prepend thumb
        self.thumbnail.save(
            os.path.basename(self.url),
            File(open(file_path, 'rb')))
```

for various reasons I need to change this to use the requests library, what would be the equivalent for temp saving an image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could skip saving to a temporary file part and use the corresponding response object directly to create the image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image # $ pip install pillow

im = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
print(im.format, im.mode, im.size)
```

Here's `requests` analog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests # $ pip install requests
from PIL import Image # $ pip install pillow

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True # handle spurious Content-Encoding
im = Image.open(r.raw)
print(im.format, im.mode, im.size)
```

I've tested it with `Pillow` 2.9.0 and `requests` 2.7.0. It should work since [`Pillow` 2.8](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html).

Comment: This also works on `requests~=2.26.0` and `Pillow~=9.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

You can write to a io.BytesIO:

```
import requests

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get(self.url)
b = BytesIO(r.content)
size = 350, 350
img = Image.open(b)
img.thumbnail(size)
img.save("foo.thumbnail", "JPEG")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/stocksearch/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 148, in dirname
    i = p.rfind(sep) + 1
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: What is `Imagelib.open`?

Comment: I have an Image class so I imported the PILLOW Image class as Imagelib

Comment: I added a full working example using PIL to save a thumbnail

Comment: you could [use `r.raw` instead of `BytesIO(r.content)` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32859290/4279)