# How to Find Link Associated with Keyword using Python, Requests, and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, shopify

I am very new python requests and beautiful soup so my code is probably really bad.

What I have now:

```
f = open('sites.txt','r')
sitelist = []
for line in f:
    sitelist.append(line.strip())
getsites = ['']
print(sitelist)
for i in range(len(sitelist)):
    getsites.append(sitelist[i])

for i in range(len(sitelist)):
    temp = requests.get(sitelist[i])
    data = temp.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for url in soup.find_all("Yeezy"):
        print(element.find_previous_sibling('loc'))
        print(url.text)
```

Example of XML File I am parsing:

```
<url>
<loc>
https://www.a-ma-maniere.com/products/beanie-502805f16-black-white
</loc>
<lastmod>2016-12-24T22:25:05Z</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0626/9065/products/502805F16-1.jpg?v=1472499019
</image:loc>
<image:title>Alexander Wang: Beanie (Black/White)</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
```

What I want to do is grab a keyword via the  then print the link associated with it stored in .

Comment: What is a sample of the keywords for which you're looking? Which XML field do you think best corresponds to your keyword (i.e. where are you looking in the XML for your keyword)?

Comment: The keywords appear in the <image:title> tag, so for example in this xml I would be searching for "Alexander Wang" and trying to find the product location in the correspond <loc> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For find all you need to give it a tag to look for.  If you only want tags of that type that contain the word "Yeezy" then in your for loop check to see if the text of the tag is the string you are looking for.  If it is the string you are looking for then you have the element want and can print the url.

For most urls this is simply

```
for url in soup.find_all('a')
    if "Yeezy" in url.get_text():
        print(url['href'])
```

For yours more like

```
for url in soup.find_all('url')
    if url.find('image:title') and url.loc:
        if "Yeezy" in url.find('image:title').get_text()
            print(url.find('image:loc').get_text())
```

For additional information visit [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Because you are trying to get an image at this point you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853980/temporarily-retrieve-an-image-using-the-requests-library) as well.  You'll need a library that can read and store images rather than trying to access it as a builtin python object.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: It will throw that error if it doesn't find anything.  Occasionally you will come accross tags that don't have the field you are looking for. I editted the answer to hopefully solve that issue.

Comment: Hey, I updated my script and am trying to make it so after it grabs the link of the product script it grabs that specific products xml file and grabs its variant to add the product to your cart (Shopify Sites). But I am running into an error on my second loop,

Comment: Specifically on this line:
`soup2 = BeautifulSoup(prod_data, "html.parser")`
prod_data is(prod_link refers to the link found in previous loop):
 `prod_data = requests.get(prod_link)`

Comment: I've added an additional reference to the end of the answer so that you can look into something called [PIL](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow).  It should help with the error you are getting now.