# How to find out if two images (with different sizes) are the same

Tags: python, web-scraping, matching

I have a setting where I want to compare two images' URLs found in a website and I want to find out if they contain the same image, regardless of the image size.

If the two images have the same size, I simply expect the two arrays to be identical.

However, my problem is how to detect if they are the same image when the size is different? (Example: [URL1](https://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/140225160936-levin-mccain-1024x576.png), [URL2](https://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/140225160936-levin-mccain-640x360.png)).

```
from PIL import Image
import requests 
import numpy as np

def get_img_content(img_url):
    try:
        im = np.asarray(Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream=True,timeout=(60,60)).raw))
        return im
    except:
        return 0

def compare_images(img1,img2):
    if isinstance(img1,(np.ndarray)) and isinstance(img2,(np.ndarray)):
        if img1.shape == img2.shape:
            comp = img1 == img2
            return comp.all()
        else:
            #missing 
    else:
        return False 
img_url = 'https://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/140225160936-levin-mccain-1024x576.png'
img_url2 = 'https://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/140225160936-levin-mccain-640x360.png'

img1 = get_img_content(img_url)
img2 = get_img_content(img_url2)
print(compare_images(img1,img2))
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736785/11380795) out for image similarity.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *similar*? Are rotated images similar? Are differently-scaled images similar? What about changing colours (different *white-balance*)?