# Comparing image of 2 different resolution

Tags: python, image-processing

I am comparing 2 video files by separating them into their frames. After a certain time interval, 2 frames(image) are captured. These video files content are same but they are different in resolution. So i need to compare these 2 images. As they are different in resolution, I cant take their matrix Of RGB values to compare. It definitely wont match. Already tried Imagemagics but its not suitable because the images can be almost same as they are just different frames of same video. How can i differentiate between these two videos?

What i did

```
import cv2
import numpy
import math
import pytest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
# from wand.image import Image
# from wand.display import display











clip = cv2.VideoCapture('./resources/sample.m4v')
converted_clip = cv2.VideoCapture('./resources/sample_convert.mp4')
clip_nof = int(clip.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
con_clip_nof = int(converted_clip.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

original_fps = int(clip.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
convert_fps = int(converted_clip.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))




fps = int(converted_clip.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
assert fps == 30.0

assert clip_nof == con_clip_nof


id = 0
conid = 0
frame_count = 1
while(True):
    clip.set(1, id)
    converted_clip.set(1, conid)
    ret, frame = clip.read()
    ret, con_frame = converted_clip.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    original_image = frame
    converted_image = con_frame

    plt.imsave('./resources/sample_frame/img%d.jpg' %
               (frame_count), original_image)
    plt.imsave('./resources/convert_frame/img%d.jpg' %
               (frame_count), converted_image)

    print(original_image.shape,converted_image.shape)

    oh,ow,od=original_image.shape
    ch,cw,cd=converted_image.shape



    # print(oh,ow,od,ch,cw,cd)
    # resize_linear(original_image,ch,cw)
    img1=Image.open('./resources/sample_frame/img%d.jpg'%(frame_count))
    img2=Image.open('./resources/convert_frame/img%d.jpg'%(frame_count))

    original_image_rgb_list=list(img1.getdata())
    converted_image_rgb_list=list(img2.getdata())


    print(len(original_image_rgb_list),len(converted_image_rgb_list))






    id = id+original_fps*2
    conid = conid+convert_fps*2

    frame_count = frame_count+1

    if(frame_count % 50 == 0):
        print("Number of frames checked are : %d" % frame_count)

    # assert original_image == converted_image

    # print(original_image, converted_image)

    


print(id, conid)
clip.release()
converted_clip.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize the bigger image to same size of smaller image. Then use [imagehash](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) library as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736154/how-to-check-similarity-of-two-images-that-have-different-pixelization).